# What is the best material and design for building a parabolic dish?

Tags: waves, radio, metals, design

I'm currently using a homemade metallic spaghetti strainer with a wifi adapter inside it to increase my wifi adapter's signal reception, but would think that a different material, like the aluminum mesh used for the Arecibo Radio Telescope could be better?

[Why is this radio telescope's reflector spherical and not parabolic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25275/why-is-this-radio-telescopes-reflector-spherical-and-not-parabolic)

Comment: Hi Frank - what exactly are you asking here? Are you asking whether a different material would increase your signal reception more than your spaghetti strainer? Also, why did you link to that other question?

Comment: Looking for optimum: material, size, shape, pattern.. Linked to radio telescope posting as reference because that reflector is made of aluminum panels and its shape is spherical because it can't be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WiFi frequency range is pretty much the same as a standard microwave oven. The reflective coefficient of the metal mesh in the front door is above 99% and it contains no special materials.

On the other hand the shape of the reflector has a large influence. So either you can follow Martin's suggestion of a can antenna, which is widely used or buy a cheap satellite dish. Even  a small 40cm dish should boost your signal by several orders of magnitude. Both ways only provide a narrowly focused signal cone so you have to optimize the alignment carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Wifi is around 2.4GHz so a wavelength of around 12.5cm
Anything metal with holes much smaller than 12cm will work - even a mesh.

But if you don't have a parabolic dish, only a spherical one, you might do better with a [can antennea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna) see eg http://www.turnpoint.net/wireless/cantennahowto.html for details of the calculation